# Understanding a Proof about integrals

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g$ $[a,b]$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ two continuous functions ang $g$ positive. Show that there exists $\xi$ $\in$ $[a,b]$ such that $\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx$ = $f(\xi) \int_a^b g(x)dx$

proof :

Note that since $g(x)>0,$ and then:

$\inf_{x\in[a,b]}\{f(x)\}\,g(x)\le f(x)\,g(x)\le \sup_{x\in[a,b]}\{f(x)\}\,g(x) \tag 1$

Let $m=\min_{x\in[a,b]}\{f(x)\}$ and  $M=\max_{x\in[a,b]}\{f(x)\}$. Using (1) we have:
$m \le \frac{\int_a^b f(x)\,g(x)\,dx}{\int_a^b g(x)\,dx}\le M\tag 2$

From the intermediate value theorem, for any number $I$ such that $m≤I≤M$, there exists a number ξ∈(a,b) such that $f(ξ)=I$. Applying this to (2) we find that there exists a ξ∈(a,b) such that:

$f(\xi)=\frac{\int_a^b f(x)\,g(x)\,dx}{\int_a^b g(x)\,dx} \tag 3$

my problem:

How do we pass from $(1)$ to $(2)$?

Comment: Integrate the whole inequality over the interval $[a,b]$

Comment: oh true because minf and max f are constants

Answer (score 1):

If $g \equiv 0$, then it's obvious, if $g(x)>0$ on $I \subset [a,b]$ then we have :

$$mg(x) \le f(x)\,g(x) \le M g(x) $$
Those inequalities are preserved by integration, hence :

$$\int_a^bm g(x)dx\le \int_a^b f(x)\,g(x)dx\le\int_a^b Mg(x)dx$$
We can put constants out of the integrals and divide by $\int^a_b g(x)dx$ since $g(x)>0$ on $I \subset [a,b]$ , so this integral is non-equal to $0$. We find $(2)$

Comment: Than you, edited.